# likert scale toggle effect missing-Bootstrap with Blaze Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootstrap-4, toggle, meteor-blaze

I have the following html displaying a scale 1-5, I get the value that is clicked but it seems as it does not toggle or change the color when a number is clicked it only changes the color temporarily as shown in file attached

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn-toolbar mr-2" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="likert group">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle mr-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                <a class="btn btn-link disabled ml-5" disabled>Totally Not</a>
                    <label class="btn btn-success" >
                        <input type="radio" name="likert" value="1" autocomplete="off">1
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-success ">
                        <input type="radio" name="likert" value="2" autocomplete="off">2
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-success ">
                        <input type="radio" name="likert" value="3" autocomplete="off">3
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-success ">
                        <input type="radio" name="likert" value="4" autocomplete="off">4
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-success ">
                        <input type="radio" name="likert" value="5" autocomplete="off">5
                    </label>
                <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Very Much</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I make it maintain the toggle effect once it is selected?Is there something missing from the above code ?
(I use Meteor Blaze framework with Bootstrap 4)

Comment: You need to store the selection in a reactive variable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the below javascript file of npm module in meteor js file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'
```